# How can I get the URL of a file on the users' computer when using <input type = "file">?

Tags: java, html, eclipse

I'm a college student and I'm currently working on a video library in JSP. I'm working on the part where the user inserts their videos, for this I need to save the URL of the video, the path, in the code the,  `<input type=file>`, but when the user would insert a file, I can't get the URL at all, only the name of the file. I know that for security reasons, the browser can't access the users' files, but I'd like to save the URL in the database, not just the file name and type. Is there a work-around to this whole thing?

This is my code for the insert video Java Server Page:

```
            <form method="post" action =<%= string1 %>>
                    <h1>Insira o vídeo</h1>

                    <p>
                        <label>Nome do vídeo</label> <input
                            id="nome_vid" name="vid_nome" required="required"
                            type="text" placeholder="Vídeo fixolas" />
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        <label>Vídeo</label><input id="btnExplore" name="btn_file" type="file"  />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label>Thumbnail</label><input id="btnExplore2" name="btn_file2" type="file"  />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <input type="submit" value="Inserir" name="submeter" onclick = "validalogin()"/>
                    </p>    
                    <p class="link">
                    
                        <a href=<%= string2 %>>Principal</a>  
                        </a>
                    </p>    
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a folder to save those files in your project folder, so it will not facing security issues. The other way is you hardcoded the front URL + filenames. For example, **"C:\Documents" + filenames** as you can get the filename.

Comment: I know that, I've thought of that and have tried to implement it, but it's not the result I want, is there no way of getting the full URL of the file upon uploading that file? I'd like to not have to resort to that option. `<input type="file">` will allow the user to navigate their files, if I just put  **"C:\Documents" + filenames** will make the user have to upload something from that folder, I'd like the user to be able to upload from whatever directory they desire.

Comment: I don't get you. You mean you want the file path of the source but not the destination? All the files uploaded by the users supposed will be saved in the same directory (destination) on the file server.